# drop down menu links dont work

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I build a simple list and added to it css. Now the vertical menu works.. the problem is in the section of the css. The list items area is bigger than the links themselves. That means that if the user clicks on the area, nothing happens cause the links area doesnt cover all the lists items area.

```
#sidebar1 li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar1 li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;    
}
```

What I thought to do was to match the links padding or width to that of the lists width. So wherever the users clicks on the menu's item a link will be clicked. Thats problem is that i tried it and it didnt work

Comment: Please also give us the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `display: block` to make the `a` element fill the available horizontal width of the parent element:

```
#sidebar1 li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The `height: 100%` forces the `a` to inherit the full height of the parent element. Remove padding from the parent `li`, otherwise you'll enforce a space between the edges of the `a` and the `li`.

Further, in your `li` I've not only removed the `padding` (which simply causes problems as noted above), but also the `cursor: pointer`, as if the user hovers over the link the cursor will change automatically, if they're not over the link then the cursor's type, that of `pointer`, is merely confusing when clicking produces no effect:

```
#sidebar1 li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width:120px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I colored the link..and there seems to be a padding on teh right margin.....I dont know if it is a padding or a margin

Comment: And without your HTML, or a live reproduction of your HTML/CSS at, for example, [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), I'm entirely unable to help with that. Help us to help you, provide more information. And a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Move most of the styling to the A-tag and fix a few things:

```
#sidebar1 li{
list-style: none;
position: relative;
margin:0 <-- added
padding:0  <-- added.
}

#sidebar1 li a{
text-decoration:none;
color: white;
width:120px;
height: 30px;
padding:0 20px;
background-color: black;
line-height: 30px;
cursor:pointer;
display:block <-- this is important
}
```

Comment: the block elemenet still doesnt make it work.. I think you mixed things up a bit

Comment: I came up with a solution..it was to give the links a background color black,, while removing all the padding from teh list item